# Using MKTileOverlay and MKTileOverlayRenderer

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, ios7, mapbox

I'm trying using MKTileOverlay and MKTileOverlayRenderer offered in the new iOS 7 beta to add a Mapbox tile layer or Mapbox server map on an Apple map view. I put my own info in some sample code I found online to load a server map over a map view but it's creating an error that I need some help explaining. I get the error, Use of undeclared identifier 'overlay'.

```
//.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


//.m

NSString *template = @"jbailo.Lighting/tile?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}";
overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc ] initWithURLTemplate:template];
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
[_mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];


-(MKTileOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

}
```

Please tell me what I should declare overlay as and if anyone has experience using these tileOverlays  methods, feel free to give advice and suggestions.

Comment: Where do you declare `overlay`?

See how `template` is declared `NSString *template` and `mapView` is declared `MKMapView *mapView`.

Comment: I don't. I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting this error. Also, how I'm going to get that map (template) to load at addOverlay. Seems like it should work and that's how the example was wrote. I'm looking for answers...

Comment: You're getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'overlay'." because you don't declare "overlay". Try declaring it and the error should go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit

It already solves the problem of integrating Apple's MapKit in iOS7 with MapBox customized map tiles.

Answer (score 2):

You doesn't have declared overlay, silly mistake

replace this line

overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc ] initWithURLTemplate:template];

With

MKTileOverlay overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc ] initWithURLTemplate:template];

Also checkout for url,  you can use this example tile:
http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/4/2/6.png

Also Never use level: MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads for MKTileOverlay instead use
 MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels